# What word describes the feeling of "shocked by some great things and humbled"?

Tags: word-request

What word describes the feeling of  "shocked by some great things and humbled and overwhelming" ?

I vaguely remember a word which sounds like "contaminated" .

For example, one can say " I am "contaminated" by the great mother nature."

Answer (score 2):

If you were humbled by great things, such as nature, you were **awed**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/awe) has

> **awe**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> Inspire with awe.
> *they were both awed by the vastness of the forest*

If you were also shocked, then you were **overawed**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/overawe) has

> **overawe**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> Impress (someone) so much that they are silent or inhibited.
> *the eleven-year-old was overawed by the atmosphere*

So

> I am overawed by the great Mother Nature.

It does not begin with 'c' though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what word you've forgotten, but the meaning might be summed up in the phrase "bowled over"; since that is a bit informal, here are some search results for synonyms of it:
[Merriam-Webster "bowled over"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/bowled%20over)

> amazed, astonished, astounded, awestruck (also awestricken), dumbfounded (also dumfounded), dumbstruck, flabbergasted, shocked, stunned, stupefied, thunderstruck

From "wordhippo", "Confounded with surprise or wonder", floored, gobsmacked, speechless, staggered

The only one that starts with "c" is "**confounded**", which more often has a negative sense.

Another "c" word is "**captivated**"; that might fit as well.

Comment: I think you should promote **confounded**  in this answer, since the OP's 'contaminated' is negative too.

Comment: @ Weather Vane - I agree. IMH, "confounded" is much more suitable than "bowled over"

Comment: I wasn't suggesting "bowled over", only using it as a key to search for synonyms. I agree "confounded" could be a good choice, used carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have what you're looking for: "[intimidated](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/intimidated)"

> frightened or nervous because you are not confident in a situation:
> *Older people can feel very intimidated by computers.*